# How can I access dynamic labels in a labelframe, that is within a labelframe?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to access the text / values of children (labels) within a LabelFrame X, where X itself is within a LabelFrame Y and the number of children changes in tkinter.

Is there a somewhat easy way of solving this problem?

I provided a simplified version of my code below. Essentially, the number of labels changes based on certain inputs (in the example randomized).
What I want to do later on is to write a for-loop that will access each of the labels and then, based on the text/value either replace the label with a new one, or move on to the next.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import numpy as np

win = tk.Tk()
LabelFrame_level_one = ttk.LabelFrame(text = " Level 1 ")
LabelFrame_level_one.grid(column = 0, row = 0, padx = 8, pady = 4)

def click_update_button():
    delete_old_labels = LabelFrame_level_one.grid_slaves()
    for labels_ in delete_old_labels:
        labels_.destroy()

    dynamic_number = max(round(np.random.rand() * 10), 1)

    LabelFrame_level_two = ttk.LabelFrame(LabelFrame_level_one, text=" Level 2 ")
    LabelFrame_level_two.grid(column=1, row=2, padx=4, pady=4, sticky="W")

    for i in range(dynamic_number):
        ttk.Label(LabelFrame_level_two, text="Dynamic entry" + str(i)).grid(column=0, row= i, pady=3)


Update_Button = ttk.Button(win, text="Update", command=click_update_button)
Update_Button.grid(column=1, row=0)

win.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the problem? This is no different than any other python variable: save a reference, and then later use the reference. You aren't saving any references to the labels.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using tkinter to produce n labels where n is variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55104813/using-tkinter-to-produce-n-labels-where-n-is-variable)